# Get PHP print variable in Ajax request, jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I get this print variables in AJAX Request (when complete), on jQuery? I really don't know how to do this.

I've searched by this and have no result. Just a little help maybe not bad...

PHP:

```
echo "variable1=hi&variable2=hey";
```

Please help me! ^^' I found not content for do this.

I don't know if this is really possible in jQuery, but I've made this when used actionscript 3 (and actionscript 3 is similiar to js).

In actionscript-3 was so: **event.target.data.varOfEcho;**

This is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({url: "<? echo $websiteul; ?>/cleanActions?action=getProfileAbout&pId=<? echo $prData['id']; ?>", success:  function(usrAboutData){
  $("#tesstt").text(usrAboutData.usrName);
}});
```

I tried much other ways.

Comment: You are returning a string,you should be returning JSON. Do that and what you tried will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a string in php script and you are accessing value using `usrAboutData.usrName`. How is this possible. Have a look at following example:

Suppose you have following php script:

```
<?php 
    echo "variable1=hi&variable2=hey";
?>
```

then your javascript code:

```
    $.ajax({url: "<? echo $websiteul; ?>/cleanActions?action=getProfileAbout&pId=<? echo $prData['id']; ?>", success:  function(usrAboutData){
      $("#tesstt").text(usrAboutData);
    }});
```

So html element having id `tesstt` will contain `variable1=hi&variable2=hey` text.

But this is not a usual way of getting data. Using JSON object to fetch data from server gives better control over data.

if you php script is like following:

```
<?php 
    echo "{"variable1":"hi","variable2":"hey"}";
?>
```

then you can get data using following code:

```
$.ajax({url: "<? echo $websiteul; ?>/cleanActions?action=getProfileAbout&pId=<? echo $prData['id']; ?>", success:  function(usrAboutData){
          var obj = JSON.parse(usrAboutData);
          $("#tesstt").text(obj.variable1);
        }});
```

Comment: Not got it, but I got do this using split in jQuery.

Comment: which part you did not get?

Comment: I still don't know what was wrong, but it's solved by using arrays, but I guess arrays are not so fine. I will continue trying to use this jSon method so that it be right. Thanks for the help!